# Flex3 Datagrid : custom rows on a flag

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am using an mx datagrid with three columns. My dataprovider is a collection, itemList which has Item objects. Item object has a flag field 'isValid'. On meeting the condition

```
item==null || item.isValid = false
```

I want the entire row to look like a single cell (merge the columns for the row) and display a label. Here is my grid.

```
        <mx:DataGrid id="grid" dataProvider="{itemList}">   
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:ArrayList>
                <mx:GridColumn dataField="Artist" headerText="Artist"/>
                <mx:GridColumn dataField="Album" headerText="Album"/>
                <mx:GridColumn dataField="Year" headerText="Year"/>
            </mx:ArrayList>
        </mx:columns>       
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Any ideas how to do it? Couldn't find much on SO. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how `Grid`s work. Each column of the row has its own `ItemRenderer` which is defined by the `GridColumn.itemRenderer` property.

You can use [`GridColumn.itemRendererFunction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#itemRendererFunction) to create a function that will dynamically changed the item renderer based on the data in the row. So you could show nothing for a row, but you cant turn a row into one `Label`

Comment: Emm, that sounds bad.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could mimic 3 column merge, would be with item renderers.

```
package
{
    public class Item
    {
        public var Artist:String;
        public var Album:String;
        public var Year:String;
        public var isValid:Boolean;

        public function Item(artist:String, album:String, year:String, isValid:Boolean = true)
        {
            this.Artist = artist;
            this.Album = album;
            this.Year = year;
            this.isValid = isValid;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason your code didn't compile on actionscript3, I guess you have never version, but I believe this should work.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" dataProvider="{itemList}" width="100%" height="100%">   
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="artist" dataField="Artist" headerText="Artist"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="album" dataField="Album" headerText="Album"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="year" dataField="Year" headerText="Year"/>
        </mx:columns>       
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Album/Year renderer:

```
package
{
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;

    public class AlbumYearItemRenderer extends HBox implements IListItemRenderer
    {
        public var dataField:String;

        private var labelComponent:Label;
        private var _itemChanged:Boolean;
        private var _data:Item;

        override public function set data(data:Object):void
        {
            super.data = data;
            _data = data as Item;
            _itemChanged = true;
        }

        protected override function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            labelComponent = new Label();
            removeAllChildren();
            addChild(labelComponent);
        }


        protected override function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if(_itemChanged)
            {
                _itemChanged = false;

                if((_data as Item).isValid)
                {
                    labelComponent.text = _data[dataField];
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Artist renderer:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class ArtistRenderer extends Canvas implements IListItemRenderer
    {

        private var c:UIComponent;
        private var labelField:Label;
        private var textField:TextField;
        private var _itemChanged:Boolean;
        private var _data:Item;
        private var labelImage:BitmapData;

        override public function set data(data:Object):void
        {
            super.data = data;
            _data = data as Item;
            _itemChanged = true;
        }

        protected override function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            labelField = new Label();
            textField = new TextField();
            c = new UIComponent();

            removeAllChildren();
        }


        protected override function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if(_itemChanged)
            {
                _itemChanged = false;

                if(_data.isValid)
                {
                    labelField.text = _data.Artist;
                    addChild(labelField);
                }
                else
                {
                    textField.text = _data.Artist;
                    textField.width = 300;
                    labelImage = new BitmapData(textField.width, textField.height, true, 0x000000ff);
                    labelImage.draw(textField);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override function measure():void
        {
            super.measure();

            if(!_data.isValid && labelImage != null)
            {
                graphics.beginBitmapFill(labelImage);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, textField.width, textField.height);
                graphics.endFill();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the way I fill grid:

```
protected function init():void
{
    var rend1:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(ArtistRenderer);
    artist.itemRenderer = rend1;

    var rend2:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(AlbumYearItemRenderer);
    rend2.properties = {dataField: album.dataField};
    album.itemRenderer = rend2;

    var rend3:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(AlbumYearItemRenderer);
    rend3.properties = {dataField: year.dataField};
    year.itemRenderer = rend3;


    itemList.addItem(new Item("artist1", "album1", "year1"));
    itemList.addItem(new Item("artist1", "album2", "year1"));
    itemList.addItem(new Item("artist2......................INVALID!", "album1", "year1", false));
    itemList.addItem(new Item("artist2", "album1", "year2"));
}
```

NOTE: Artist renderer uses "magical" number 300 to determine `textField`'s width, this should be passed/updated with actual `DataGrid`'s width to make it expand to full grid's width.
Also column borders are seen under an invalid item's artist textField. You should either disable borders or draw a maybe white square under `textField`, but it's cosmetic job and I believe you will be able to dealt with this stuff.

[image: Sample image]